# How to get AngularJS to pick up dynamic bindings created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, datatables

One part of my code changes the route by:

```
$state.go('^.DfDocuments', {
    requestId: rowData.RequestID
});
```

However, this doesn't allow me to right click on the link and do "open in new tab".

I'd like to programatically set an a tag with a ui-sref attribute. They are being set in the rows of a jQuery datatable. I.e.

```
<a data-ui-sref="DfDocuments{requestId: 12155}">Asdf</a>
```

However, since this is coming from JavaScript (late bound?), it's not doing anything.

How can I get Angular to notice these? I believe that I need $compile or (better) $link, but not sure. Can I do those without directives?

```
$scope.GetMRender = function (columnId) {
    switch (columnId) {
    case 'Docs':
        return function(data, type, row) {
            return '<a ui-sref="^DfDocuments{requestId: ' + row.RequestID + '}">test</a>';
        };
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for $scope.apply(). See
http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html